# Changing tab text size in wxpython notebook

Tags: text, wxpython, size, wxnotebook

Is it possible to change the font size of the tab titles in a wx.Notebook?  I know how to change the tab spacing/padding with SetPadding, but I want to change the actual size of the text as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Notebook's SetFont method:

```
notebook.SetFont(wx.Font(8, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                         wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 
                         wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL))
```

This worked for me with wxPython 2.8, Python 2.7 on Ubuntu